# scrolling through children of a MovieClip subclass in haxe

Tags: flash, combobox, scroll, movieclip, haxe

In haxe I have a DropDownMenu class that extends MovieClip:

```
class DropDownMenu extends MovieClip { ...
```

TextFields are added to DropDownMenus (about 50 TextFields total):

```
// in a loop in DropDownMenu new method
addChild(myTextField);
```

When a DropDownMenu is displayed the items further down are hidden as the menu goes off the bottom of the flash player. **How can I make these DropDownMenus scroll?**

I've considered doing something on the rollout mouse event. However I imagine MovieClip provides some mechanism for scrolling its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [`DisplayObject::scrollRect`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect) for scrolling a DisplayObject's content. There's no such thing as automatic scrolling, if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: scrollRect is working for me, thanks. Is there an easy way to determine the total height of the DisplayObject/DropDownMenu?